# Sort of pattern in expressions of the form $x^z+y^z+\cdots+n^z$ and Fermat's like theorem

Tags: number-theory

So if we look at Pythagoras theorem $$x^2+y^2=z^2$$ If we look deeply we will remark a sort of pattern, which is $$\underbrace{x^{\color{red}2}+y^{\color{red}2}}_{\text{$\color{red}2$ expressions}}=\underbrace{z^{\color{red}2}}_{\text{$\color{red}2-1$ expressions}}$$
So my question is: does a  Diophantine equations of the form :$$\underbrace{x^z+y^z+\cdots+n^z}_{\text{$z$ expressions}}=\underbrace{a^z+\cdots+b^z}_{\text{$z-1$ expressions}}$$
have infinite solutions in $\mathbb{N}$ of course?

**Example:** There are infinitely many solutions for $2$ (proved by Euler: that there exists infinitely many Pythagorean triplets) but what about other natural numbers?

Furthermore, if the answer to the latter is **"No"** then does there exist a polynomial  $Q(z)$ such that the following Diophantine equation have infinitely many solutions: 
$$\underbrace{x^z+y^z+\cdots+n^z}_{\text{$z$ expressions}}=\underbrace{a^z+\cdots+b^z}_{\text{$Q(z)$ expressions}}$$

and we of course assume that $Q(z)\neq z$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If $Q(z) = z$ then there are many, many solutions...

Comment: @nik Well, we obviously look for non-trivial solutions and so we assume that $Q(z)\neq z$.

Answer (score 1):

Counting arguments predict that a given linear relation between $k$-th powers of $n$ different variables will have infinitely many primitive integer solutions (unless prevented by congruence conditions or inequalities) if $n > k$,  and finitely many for $n < k$.

For $n=k$ either possibility could hold and it depends  on the specific equation. $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ has no nonzero integer solutions, $x^3 + y^3 = 2z^3$ has $(1,1,1,)$ as the only primitive solution, and $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = w^4$ has infinitely many primitive solutions.

Primitive means not a multiple of another solution.

When $k=z$ and $n=z + (z-1)$ it is the abundant case, $n > k$, and there should be infinitely many solutions or, potentially, even a polynomial parameterized family of primitive solutions, but proving this for any particular equation of that type can be a hard unsolved problem.

Comment: I didn't understand well